# Unable to connect to Testnet Sepolia

Tags: contract-deployment, javascript, smart-contract-wallets

Command:

```
npx hardhat --network sepolia run scripts/deploy.js
```

Getting error messages:

```
* Invalid account: #0 for network: sepolia - private key too long, expected 32 bytes
  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.etherscan.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid account: #0 for network: etherscan - private key too short, expected 32 bytes
```

Hardhat.cofig:

```
// import config before anything else import {config as dotEnvConfig} from dotEnvConfig();
/**
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
*/

require ('dotenv').config();
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("hardhat-deploy");


{
}

const {ALCHEMY_API_KEY,ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,PRIVATE_KEY} = process.env;
const ERC1155 = require("@openzeppelin/contracts/build/contracts/ERC1155.json");



module.exports =  {
    defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
    networks: {
      hardhat: {
      },
      sepolia: {
        url: "process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY",
        accounts: [`0x${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`],
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: "process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY",
        accounts: [`0x${ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}`],
      },
    },
    solidity: {
      version: "0.8.9",
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 200
        }
      }
    },
    paths: {
      sources: "./contracts",
      tests: "./test",
      cache: "./cache",
      artifacts: "./artifacts"
    },
    mocha: {
      timeout: 40000
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct private key?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the url and PK in a simple way, change your code to this:

Pass the URL, not only the API key.

```
       sepolia: {
            url: process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY, // Pass the full URL here
            accounts: [PRIVATE_kEY], //pass the wallet private key, not the api key
        },
        etherscan: {
            apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY, // Pass the full URL here
            accounts: [PRIVATE_kEY],//pass the wallet private key, not the api key
        },
```

Comment: @Gujarati No, I never used that and my code always runs fine, don't know how do you come with this.

Comment: because it's run very well in my system.

Comment: Good for you, I will always write the easiest and simplest answers, unless there's a need to add more characters. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I realized that I was using the wrong private key and use your hardhat.config example and removed my etherscan API just to see if less is better and get it to work but I still got an error 

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH8 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
MacBook-Pro:erc1155-contract complexdesign$ npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

Invalid account: #0 for network: sepolia - private key too long, expected 32 bytes

Comment: It's clearly a wrong private key, Make sure to pass the right private key in the right way. How are you passing the private key?

Comment: I'm passing in my .env file as "0x then my private key", the private key is from metamask I think I have the right one

Comment: I removed the private key just to test and see if it will connect to Sepolia network. 

Got an error:
{
  input: '"https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/API-KEY",',
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
} 

How I change the hardhat config below 

module.exports =  {
    defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
    networks: {
      hardhat: {
      },
      sepolia: {
        url: process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY, // Pass the full URL here
        chainID:11155111 
      },
    },

Comment: INVALID_URL is ttps://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/API KEY is the error I'm getting

Comment: Okay so you are making two mistakes, I already told you in my answer that you shouldn't write 0x in front of the private key. And pass the complete URL with https. The full URL is present in Alchemy Dashboard, copy the complete URL.

Comment: I removed the Private Key entirely mentioned in my last post and using the correct URL for Alchemy still getting that error.

Comment: I've produced a new error since making those corrections.

MacBook-Pro:erc1155-contract complexdesign$ npx hardhat --network sepolia run scripts/deploy.js

Compiled 15 Solidity files successfully
ProviderError: Must be authenticated!